# problem with printing my sorted struct list

Tags: c

I'm making a program where I'm entering an activity hours for dogs and then sums the hour for each activity and after that the program print each dog one after another from the dog with higher sum of hours of activites to the lowest
now I did sort the list and made a print function , but still doesn't work , it prints either 2 of them if the first dog I entered has the highest sum of hours and the seconde is the lowers in the right order, but if there first dog was the one with the lowest and the seconde one was the one with the highest it just prints the first dog ( the loswet one) and doesn't even print the seconde dog.

input:

```
2
any1
6
6
6
any2
3
3
3
```

Actual output:

```
any1 6 6 6
```

Expected output:

```
any2 3 3 3  
any1 6 6 6
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 30
#define GRADE 100.0
#define AVG_SLEEP 12
#define AVG_WALK 1.25
#define AVG_PLAY 2
#define TEN 10.0
#define EIGHT 8.0
typedef struct dog* dogPtr;
typedef struct dog
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]; /*30*/
    double sleep;
    double walk;
    double playtime;
    dogPtr next;
} Dog;
            
double calculateGrade (dogPtr dog);
void addDog(dogPtr* fitBarkList);
void printDogList(dogPtr fitBarkList);
void freeList (dogPtr list);
            
int main()
{
    int amount_of_dogs;
    int i;
     
    dogPtr list = NULL;
    printf("Welcome to FitBarkList\n");
    printf("Enter the amount of dogs: \n");
    if(!scanf("%d", &amount_of_dogs))
    {
        printf("Input Error\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (amount_of_dogs <1)
    {
        printf("Enter the amount of dogs: \n");
        if(!scanf("%d",&amount_of_dogs))
        {
            printf("Input Error\n");
            
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    for(i = 0; i < amount_of_dogs; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter dog number %d\n", i+1 );
        addDog(&list);
    }
    
    printDogList(list);
    freeList(list);
    return 0;
}

/**this function frees the allocated memory*/
void freeList (dogPtr list)
{
    if(list != NULL)
    {
        freeList(list->next);
        free(list);
    }
}

void addDog(dogPtr* fitBarkList)
{
    dogPtr tmp=*fitBarkList,tmp2=NULL,curr;
    dogPtr p = (dogPtr)malloc(sizeof(Dog));
    if(p == NULL )
    {
        printf("allocation failed\n");
        
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter the dog's name: \n");
    scanf("%s", p->name);
    printf("Enter the dog's average sleeping time: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &p->sleep);
    printf("Enter the dog's average walking time: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &p->walk);
    printf("Enter the dog's average play time: \n");
    scanf("%lf", &p->playtime);
    
    p->next=NULL;
    
    if (*fitBarkList == NULL)
    {
        *fitBarkList=p;
        return ;
    }
    curr=p;
    while (tmp!=NULL)
    {
        if (calculateGrade(curr) < calculateGrade (tmp))
        {
            tmp2=tmp;
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
        else
        {
            return ;
        }
    }
    if (tmp != NULL)
    {
        curr=tmp2->next;
        tmp->next=curr;
    }
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        tmp2->next=curr;
        curr->next=NULL;
    }
}

/**this function prints the grade of the dog then shows the total grade*/
void printDogList(dogPtr fitBarkList)
{
    dogPtr curr=fitBarkList;
    if(curr == NULL)
    {
        return ;
    }
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s \n", curr->name);
        printf("Sleeping grade %.2f \n", curr->sleep);
        printf("Play time grade: %.2f \n", curr->playtime);
        printf("Walking grade: %.2f \n", curr->walk);
        printf("Total grade: %.2f \n", calculateGrade(curr));
        curr=curr->next;
    }
}
/**this function to calculate the grades for each activity*/
double calculateGrade(dogPtr dog)
{
    double sleep = dog->sleep,
        walk = dog->walk,
        playtime = dog->playtime;
    
    if (sleep == 12.0)
        sleep = GRADE;
    else if (sleep < AVG_SLEEP)
        sleep = GRADE - ((12.0 - sleep) * TEN);
    else if (sleep > AVG_SLEEP)
        sleep = GRADE - ((sleep - AVG_SLEEP) * TEN);
    if (walk == AVG_WALK&& walk>=0.25)
        walk = GRADE;
    else if (walk > AVG_WALK )
        walk = GRADE - ((walk - AVG_WALK) * EIGHT);
    else if (sleep <= 0.25)
        walk = GRADE - GRADE;
    else if (walk < AVG_WALK && walk > 0.25)
        walk = GRADE - ((AVG_WALK - walk) * GRADE);
    if (playtime == AVG_PLAY)
        playtime = GRADE;
    else if (playtime > AVG_PLAY)
        playtime = GRADE - ((playtime - AVG_PLAY) * EIGHT);
    else if (playtime < AVG_PLAY)
        playtime = GRADE - 60.0;
    else if (AVG_PLAY>playtime && playtime>1.0)
        playtime=GRADE-(GRADE*(AVG_PLAY-playtime));
    return sleep + walk + playtime;
}
```

Comment: You update the list head, `fitBarkList`, only if the list is empty, but it should also be updated when the new dog has the highest grade so far and the node is inserted at the front. In that case, `tmp2 == NULL`.

Comment: @MOehm you mean I need to make a condition for when the list is not empty?

Comment: If the list head changes, you must update its head via `fitBarkList`. You do that, but only when the list is empty. If the iist is not empty, but the new dog's grade is higher than the old list head, the new dog will be the new head. If you don't update the list head, your calling function will still think the old dog is first. When you print, you therefore start printing at the second-best dog. If you enter the dogs in reverse order, you will end up printing just the dog with the lowest grade. Therefore, if `tmp2 == NULL`, you should set `*fitBarkList = curr`.

Comment: (I have a feeling, that `curr` in this case really should be spelled `cur`.)

Comment: @MOehm oh I see, thank you

Comment: Oh, there's more: Don't return in the `else` branch. That will mean you don't insert the node at all. I guess you have put that `return` statement there, because otherwise you'd get a segmentation fault. Instead, test `tmp2` for `NULL` and update either `*fitBarkList` or `tmp2->next`.

Comment: @MOehm I think you should let sleeping dogs lie. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you find the new place where to insert the new dog, you walk the list if there is a next dog and if the new dog's grade is below the current dog's grade. (I've renamed the two iterators `curr` and `prev` for clarity.)

When you insert the new dog, `p`, the next dog is the current dog, `p->next = curr`. If the current dog's grade is the smallest of if the list was empty, `curr` is `NULL`, which is fine. You don't need to treat an empty list as special case.

Now, if `prev == NULL`, your new dog ist the current best. There is no previous node, so update the head pointer via `*fitBarkList`. Otherwise, update the `next` field of the previous node:

```
    dogPtr p = create_node(...);         // alloc and read stuff

    dogPtr curr = *fitBarkList;          // p goes before this ...
    dogPtr prev = NULL;                  // ... and after this
    
    while (curr && calculateGrade(p) < calculateGrade (curr)) {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    
    p->next = curr;
    
    if (prev == NULL) {                  // first node
        *fitBarkList = p;
    } else {                             // subsequent nodes
        prev->next = p;
    }
```

Comment: No, curr is the head pointer. (The original code has `curr = p` as alias, but I've changed that.) Why should `p->next = curr` create an infinite loop? You insert the new node `p` between `prev` and `curr`. Both `prev` and `curr` may be `NULL`.

Comment: (Perhaps `prev` and `curr` could be even better called `curr` and `next` or `prev` and `next`.)

Comment: yes curr it equals to p before the loop and yes there was in infinite loop when p->next=curr

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include my definitions in the actual code. Sorry for that. (The original code assigned `curr = p` and from then on just used `curr` instead of `p`, but never modified it. So I repurposed that variable as iterator.)

Comment: @MOehm is code replacing my code or i should add it to it or change it like this one ?

Comment: The code replaces your code if you use your node allocation and input instead of `dogPtr p = create_node(...);`. (That is, keep everything rom `malloc` to the last `scanf`, replace the rest.)